# How related are two relatives?

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

The [coefficient of relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_relationship#Human_relationships) refers to how much DNA two persons have in common. A parent has 50% common DNA with their child (unless the parents are related), so to calculate it we have to find all pairs of directed disjoint paths starting at same node (common ancestor) and ending at each of the two siblings, and sum 2^-(m+n) for all pairs of paths of length m and n.

Your program should accept a list of pairs of numbers (or names if you prefer) representing parent-child relations followed by another pair of number for which it should output the coefficient of relationship (either as a fraction, a decimal number, or a percentage).

For example:

```
Format: [list of parent-child relations] pair of relatives we want to compare -> expected output
-----------------------------------------------
[(1,2)] (1, 2) -> 50% (parent-child)
[(1,2), (2, 3), (3, 4)] (2, 3) -> 50% (still parent-child, make sure your path pairs are disjoint)
[(1,3), (2, 3)] (1, 2) -> 0% (not related, make sure your paths are directed)
[(1, 2), (2, 3)] (1, 3) -> 25% (grandparent-child)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)] (3, 4) -> 50% (siblings)
[(1, 2), (1, 3)] (2, 3) -> 25% (half-siblings)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)] (4, 5) -> 25% (aunt/uncle-nephew/niece)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6)] (5, 6) -> 12.5% (cousins)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (3, 9), (7, 9), (4, 10), (8, 10)] (9, 10) -> 25% (double cousins)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)] (3, 5) -> 75% (parent-(child-with-sibling) incest)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)] (1, 3) -> 75% ((parent-and-grandparent)-(child-with-child) incest)
```

No person will have more than two parents and there will be no cycles in it. You can also assume that the number is the order in which they were born (so `a < b` in all `(a, b)`).

Comment: Can you clarify the task and what exactly `m` and `n` represent? If you would give a more concrete formula or something, it would be fine. What exactly do the pairs in the input represent?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: The lengths of the paths to both siblings.

Comment: Also, can you have one example of input and an explanation (with steps) on how you obtained that output?

Comment: 50% seems awfully high for cousins. By my calculation, that should be 12.5%, since 1 and 2 each have path lengths of 2 to 5 and 6, so they should contribute 1/16th each, for a total of 1/8th.

Comment: @isaacg: Fixed it, I forgot to change the number after copy-pasting.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: In the case of uncle-nephew, we have disjoint path pairs (1 -> 3 -> 5, 1-> 4), (2 -> 3 -> 5, 2-> 4). Both pairs would have m=2, n=1, so 2^-3 for each pair * 2 pairs gives 2^-2 = 25%

Comment: @Runemoro Add it to the challenge, do not leave it here, in the comments.

Comment: Can we assume **a < b** for all pairs **(a,b)**?

Comment: @Zgarb No because the pairs represent directed edge.

Comment: @user202729 But the graph is acyclic, so it can be represented using such edges. All test cases satisfy it as well.

Comment: Can we assume the input graph is acyclic?

Comment: @isaacg Hmm, I assumed it is (otherwise time travel would be involved since someone is their own ancestor), but it isn't explicitly said in the challenge text...

Comment: Also, can we assume no one has more than 2 parents?

Comment: @isaacg: Yes, (a, b) represents "a is the parent of b", so there will be no (directed) cycles and no person with over 2 parents.

Comment: The half-siblings example (i.e `[(1, 3), (2, 3)] (3, 4)`) seems to be missing a pairing: either `(1, 4)` or `(2, 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>259</strike> <strike>247</strike> 226 bytes

```python
lambda l,a,b:sum(2**-len({*m}^{*n})for v in{*sum(l,())}for m in p(v,a,l)for n in p(v,b,l)if not{*zip(m,m[1:])}&{*zip(n,n[1:])})
p=lambda i,j,l:sum([[[r+[i]for r in p(y,j,l)],[[y,x]]][j==y]for x,y in l if i==x],[])+[[i]]*(i==j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LboMwEEX3/YpZVR5nIhVI85L8JY4rgdqoRraxXBpBEd9ObHBXZ@6dOw8/9t@dq5YgboupbfNZg6GamuvPr2Ul53vz5djE7fwxcTfjvQvwAO0mnvqGGOKcPBs98OwRR80acv9GEw19B9f1E//TnlmysrgqnF837chtGl@8yB9oasmsH0gpw05qlVaGbeWYmqhIypEGpZRshRjXwEBjihiI97QQQ8wo3Mk4rjiLRouLD9r1LDDJCoIKCRIPiWXWZdbvBKfMc@Ix62PWFcEl8ZR5ICjeUnFeC0XA2WUtEZcn)

This can probably be golfed down quite a bit, but for now I'm just happy it works.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 206 bytes:

```py
lambda l,a:(a in l)/2+sum(2**-len((x|y)-(x&y))for x in f(a[0],l,a)for y in f(a[1],l,a)if x&y)
def f(n,l,o,p=[],K=1):
 for a,b in l:
  if(b==n)&(K:=[a,b]!=o):yield from f(a,l,o,p+[b]);K=0
 if K:yield{*p+[n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZFBbsIwEEX3OcVUlZANpo0dTCCVt2xyhNSLRBA1UnCilEpEbc@eeuxAqwoWtKv5/jP/zQTa/vDSmGjVdsNGPQ91vi@2OdQsT0gOlYGaPorZ69ueiOl0Xu8MIcePns7JcdJTWjYdHHGqJHkWamZjzutPHvdeVQLOB9tdaW1jvYa1KtMsVZwmAWAmZ4XbZ59QlaRQytAJSROV2Y6@Uw1N@mpXb6Hsmj3CPWWWFZo@pSoMbApSP/M@tb7Rn0PbVeZANiTLOAOhNQMvKIV7GQa/2rYrGERYIwYLfTYujUfnrmbf0KvMcbVnCXmBxXHljxPE6QR3y9WL@Ykubqd7uHTxBYq/xX166TASBWK4eLgFZHPxWFdYl@N7Ob7tojXWeKx2IQ9RrJxAtXbqP58g9dlATCyv/d4X/9VYDl8)

Comment: [206](https://tio.run/##pZFBbsIwEEX3OcVUlZANpo0dTCCVt2xyhNSLRBA1UnCilEpEbc@eeuxAqwoWtKv5/jP/zQTa/vDSmGjVdsNGPQ91vi@2OdQsT0gOlYGaPorZ69ueiOl0Xu8MIcePns7JcdJTWjYdHHGqJHkWamZjzutPHvdeVQLOB9tdaW1jvYa1KtMsVZwmAWAmZ4XbZ59QlaRQytAJSROV2Y6@Uw1N@mpXb6Hsmj3CPWWWFZo@pSoMbApSP/M@tb7Rn0PbVeZANiTLOAOhNQMvKIV7GQa/2rYrGERYIwYLfTYujUfnrmbf0KvMcbVnCXmBxXHljxPE6QR3y9WL@Ykubqd7uHTxBYq/xX166TASBWK4eLgFZHPxWFdYl@N7Ob7tojXWeKx2IQ9RrJxAtXbqP58g9dlATCyv/d4X/9VYDl8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>188</s> <s>166</s> 154 bytes

```
e_~h~f_:=4Tr[2^-Tr[Length/@#]&/@Select[Flatten[Tuples[i@r_:=If[#==r,{{r}},FindPath[g,#,r,∞,All]];i/@f]&/@VertexList[g=Rule@@@e],1],DisjointQ@@Rest/@#&]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHdSsMwGL33KQqFXX0y@7tOKUSQgbCLOcduQhxlfm0jXZU0A6F01z6FD@eL1KTtysAqai56Tk@@c05IdpFMcRdJvo3qGjeH9BBvLkN3Jaj9cK6@c8wTmY6JyUZjco8ZbiWdZZGUmNPV/iXDgnIilOU2pmYYCihLUVUw4/njQkXTBEwQ8PH2DtdZxtgVH5NYR61RSHyd80LSJFzuMySEIAOLwQ0vnp55Lu8IWWIhVfWIsXohlETLlJalBYatKoyWMDB6UWk2GI5GBwy36gU1dHYcc3r1x4xuc8Br6eiTKvtY1XSejtt9yPcnGUxrw7zG5mryN1vr8hu7p8mv7Wp60mGg0e/@fR2gVtB1TDVOOlRd1oUmQUM0mzbsP6f2ql4YvsqvD1Sx@hM)